# Python: convert a string from any format into CamelCase

Tags: python, regex, camelcasing

Please explain the below Python code to me. This answer works when submitted on CodeWars and I want help understanding the ins and outs of it. What is happening at each step of this program?

```py
from re import split

def camelize(string):
    return ''.join(a.capitalize() for a in split('([^a-zA-Z0-9])', string)
       if a.isalnum())
```

Here is a test example:
camelize("example name")   # => ExampleName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure! Regex stuff can be hard to just look at and understand at the start. First, let's break it down into the order things happen. Let's use the example input `"test_of wORd editor"`

First, we split the string into a list with `split('([^a-zA-Z0-9])', string)`. This is split on every character that *isn't* a letter (uppercase or lowercase) or a number. This would convert our input into `['test', '_', 'of', ' ', 'wORd', ' ', 'editor']`.

Next, we are going to only keep part of our list by asking if each element in our list is alphanumeric with `.isalnum()`. If not, we ignore that part of our list. If it is alpha-numeric, we call `.capitalize()` on each element in the list, which converts the element to all lowercase with the exception of the first character, which is uppercase. This is a built-in python function that is doing the meat of what you want. These two parts together are done using [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python). I'm going to assume you know what that is. The output of this will be `['Test', 'Of', 'Word', 'Editor']`.

Lastly, we need to join the list together to be a string again. `''.join()` combines every element of the list together without spaces, returning `'TestOfWordEditor'`.

Answer (score 3):

The camelize function will receive the string `string` and will split it in strings of consecutive alphanumeric characters

```
split('([^a-zA-Z0-9])', "example name") # => ['example', ' ', 'name']
```

Each string of the split result will be capitalized

```
[a.capitalize() for a in ['example', ' ', 'name']] # => ['Example', ' ', 'Name']
```

And will be filtered with `isalnum()` condition which checks the string contains only alphanumeric characters (Deleting the space element of the array)

```
[a.capitalize() for a in ['example', ' ', 'name'] if a.isalnum()] # => ['Example', 'Name']
```

Then will be joined using the separator `''` (Empty string).

```
''.join(a.capitalize() for a in ['example', ' ', 'name'] if a.isalnum()) # => 'ExampleName'
```

Answer (score 0):

Input to function is string.

`isalnum()`  :The method `isalnum()` checks whether the string consists of alphanumeric characters.

`.join()` : Python String join() ,The join() is a string method which returns a string concatenated with the elements of an iterable

`capitalize()`: It returns a copy of the string with only its first character capitalized.

`split()` :The method split() returns a list of all the words in the string.

Understanding above will return your output for given input string